# First line of sub before loop

Tags: vba

This function breaks up one long continuous string into smaller ones and adds a prefix and suffix/

This line of code is giving me problems I need it because the first prefix is different to the others but it causes the first line to be produced twice not sure how to rewrite the line /code overcome this?

```
.WriteLine "s = """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, 1, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"
```

Here is the full suc:

```
Sub StringBuilder(intSize As Integer, Optional AtomSize As Long = 3)
Dim i As Long
Dim strInput As String

strInput = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\input.txt").ReadAll
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\output.txt", True)
    .WriteLine "s = """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, 1, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"
  For i = 1 To Len(strInput) - intSize * AtomSize Step intSize * AtomSize
    .WriteLine "s = s & """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, i, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"
  Next
  .WriteLine "s = s & """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, i, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: For i = 2 To Len(strInput) - intSize * AtomSize Step intSize * AtomSize ?

Comment: Why don't you abstract out the part of the code that breaks up the string into a separate function and separate it from the file IO? That would be cleaner and easier to debug. Also -- it isn't a bad idea to close files explicitly.

Comment: For i = 2 To Len(strInput) - intSize * AtomSize Step intSize * AtomSize tried this but seems to mess up he output

Comment: John Coleman could you show example code for what you're suggesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function which can be used to divide a string into groups:

```
Function GroupString(s As String, groupSize As Long, _
        Optional delim As String = ",", _
        Optional prefix As String = "", _
        Optional postfix As String = "") As String

    Dim n As Long, m As Long, i As Long
    Dim chunks As Variant

    n = Len(s)
    m = Int(n / groupSize)
    If n Mod groupSize = 0 Then
        ReDim chunks(0 To m - 1)
    Else
        ReDim chunks(0 To m) 'includes final chunk of size < groupSize
    End If

    For i = 0 To m - 1
        chunks(i) = Mid(s, 1 + i * groupSize, groupSize)
    Next i

    If n Mod groupSize > 0 Then
        chunks(m) = Mid(s, 1 + m * groupSize) 'final chunk
    End If

    GroupString = prefix & Join(chunks, delim) & postfix

End Function
```

To test it:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myString As String

    myString = "abcd"
    Debug.Print GroupString(myString, 2, , "[", "]")

    myString = "This is a very long string, it would be nice if it were split into several lines, where each line is assigned to a variable"
     Debug.Print GroupString(myString, 20, """" & vbCrLf & "s = s & """, "s = """, """")
End Sub
```

With output:

```
[ab,cd]
s = "This is a very long "
s = s & "string, it would be "
s = s & "nice if it were spli"
s = s & "t into several lines"
s = s & ", where each line is"
s = s & " assigned to a varia"
s = s & "ble"
```

To use it for your problem: read the input file into a string, and then in a single write operation, use a single write operation to write the result of the function applied to the string, using a call similar to the second example in my test code.

Answer (score 1):

Simple change

`.WriteLine "s = """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, 1, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"`

To

`.WriteLine "s = """`

```
Sub StringBuilder(intSize As Integer, Optional AtomSize As Long = 3)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strInput As String

    strInput = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\input.txt").ReadAll
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\output.txt", True)
        .WriteLine "s = """
      For i = 1 To Len(strInput) - intSize * AtomSize Step intSize * AtomSize
        .WriteLine "s = s & """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, i, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"
      Next
      .WriteLine "s = s & """ & Trim$(Mid$(strInput, i, intSize * AtomSize)) & """"
    End With

End Sub
```